# Querying Data with a predicate and paging using Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jpa, spring-data

I have had the misfortune of working in Java for some time, coming from the .net world. Ranting aside, I am simply looking to implement a Repository that can handle use of predicates and must have pagination. I am unable to find a good way to do this.

```
// IContactRepository.java
public interface IContactRepository extends Repository<Contact,Long> {

}
// Application.java
contactRepo.findAll(predicate, new PageRequest(0,10));
```

I want to to be able to find contacts with contact name containing search term or contact phone number containing search term and then get first 10 matches.

In the .net world, if I was not using an orm I would use sql server's awesome TSQL to get what I want but stuck with Oracle here. I would otherwise use some ORM and pass a lambda to the query function as predicate.

Comment: Do you want to add predicates dynamically?

Comment: Right now the predicate needs to be dynamic enough so that i can do a like query on either contact name or contact number and return a paged result.

Comment: Downvote because I think moving to Java from C# is a misfortune ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my configuration I am also using JPA and spring. (FOR STATIC PREDICATES. If you want to add predicates(search terms) dynamically please let me know.)

```
// IContactRepository.java
public interface IContactRepository extends CrudRepository<Contact,Long>, PagingAndSortingRepository<Contact, Long>  {
    List<Contact> findByContactNameLikeAndContactPhoneLike(String name, String phone, Pageable pageable)
}
```

I tried Pageable with CrudRepo and it works fine.
And for the lambda you are right :)

In my configuration your implementation looks like this :

```
IContactRepository contactRepo = context.getBean(IContactRepository.class);
List<Contacts> results = contactRepo.findByContactNameLikeAndContactPhoneLike("%CA%","%090%" , new PageRequest(1, 20));
```

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html

Please have a look **Query creation** under **1.2.2 Defining query methods**

Comment: This worked for me for what I wanted to do. Thanks for not being judgemental on my noob question.

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing you are looking at `Predicate` because you want to be able to execute any arbitrarily complex query.

However there is no `findAll(Predicate, Pageable)` method.
I suggest that you check out `Specification` and `JpaSpecificationExecutor`. Your code would look like this:

```
public interface IContactRepository extends JpaRepository<Contact,Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Contact> {

}
```

Then you would have access to the method `findAll(Specification, Pageable)`. And as per your requirement, `Specification` is a Functional Interface, so you can use a lambda to easily pass in an implementation.

Check out section `2.5` from the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.6.0.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html) for more details.

[Here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.5.2.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/domain/Specification.html#toPredicate%28javax.persistence.criteria.Root,%20javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery,%20javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder%29) is the Javadoc of `Specification` and [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.6.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaSpecificationExecutor.html) is the Javadoc of `JpaSpecificationExecutor`

Also if you have to endure the pain of Java, you should probably drop the `I` in `IContactRepository` :). Java code usually forgoes that .NET practice

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/1.7.2.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/querydsl/QueryDslPredicateExecutor.html#findAll(com.mysema.query.types.Predicate, org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable) is where i found the findAll variant I was trying to use.

Comment: I didn't realise you where looking at the QueryDSL variant! My bad!

Answer (score 2):

Thats my implementation maybe help to you:

```
@Override
public Page<Advert> findActiveAdverts(String searchValue, String availability, Long branchId, Long categoryId, Pageable pageable) {
    Page<Advert> adverts = advertRepository.findAll(new Specification<Advert>() {
        @Override
        public javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate toPredicate(Root<Advert> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
            List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

            predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get(Advert_.ACTIVE), true));

            if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(searchValue)) {
                predicates.add(cb.or(
                        cb.like(root.get(Advert_.TITLE), "%" + searchValue + "%"),
                        cb.like(root.get(Advert_.EXPLANATION), "%" + searchValue + "%"))
                );
            }

            return cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
        }
    }, pageable);
    return adverts;
}
```